# Font of \schemeref labels (chemstyle)

Tags: fonts, chemstyle

I'm using Chemstyle to label the compounds in my thesis and am using the a \renewcommand to re-size the labels. However, this seems to change the font as well. I need the numbers to be in Arial 8 pt or another non-serif font.

Here's an example:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[left=4.0 cm,right=2.0 cm,top=2.0 cm,bottom=2.0 cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{chemstyle} 
    \renewcommand*{\schemerefformat}{\fontsize{5pt}{6pt}\textbf{}} %set size of chemlabels


    \begin{document}

    \leavevmode\compound*{cmpd1}
    \compound*{cmpd2}
    \compound*{cmpd4}

   Arene \compound{cmpd1} was used to obtain a diastereomeric mixture upon complexation that was easily separable by column chromatography (\ref{sch2}). After hydrolysis of the ester the two enantiomeric complexes \textit{pS}-\compound{cmpd4} and \textit{pR}-\compound{cmpd4} were obtained.

    \begin{scheme}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Chiral resolution.}
    \schemeref[TMP1]{cmpd1}
    \schemeref[TMP2]{cmpd2}
    \schemeref[TMP4]{cmpd4}
    \includegraphics[width=0.82\textwidth]{1-3.eps}
      \label{sch2}
    \end{scheme}

    \end{document}
```

And the output:
[image]

Here's the dropbox link to the MWE if needed: [Dropbox Folder with example and image](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o37wza5lfhea5nl/AADFV3dIEppH1XeFeDMjRZ7ma)

Comment: edit: Accidentally added the jpg instead of the eps to the dropbox - fixed now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add bold formatting via `\schemerefformat` – setting the labels bold is done by the underlying package that provides the numbering of compounds. Unless specified otherwise this is the [`chemcompounds`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemcompounds) package. `\schemerefformat` adds *additional* formatting for the labels in schemes. Per default its definition is

```
\newcommand*\schemerefformat{\textsf}
```

*i.e.* it uses sans serif font for the labels in schemes. Note that it uses `\textsf` *without* the trailing argument. Your definition

```
\renewcommand*{\schemerefformat}{\fontsize{5pt}{6pt}\textbf{}}
```

does *not* use sans serif which is why you're getting none. Also `\textbf{}` has no effect since you've added an empty argument to `\textbf`. The labels still are bold since as I've said above this is done by `chemcompounds`.

You need a definition like

```
\renewcommand*\schemerefformat{\tiny\textsf}
```

Also a definition using `\sffamily` (a font switch without argument) would do:

```
\renewcommand*\schemerefformat{\tiny\sffamily}
```

Since I couldn't find the EPS in the Dropbox link you provided I use a different scheme for the following example:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: on }
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: on }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemstyle} 

\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\compound{cmpd1,cmpd2}

\begin{scheme}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{First example}
  \schemeref[TMP1]{cmpd1}
  \schemeref[TMP2]{cmpd2}
  \includegraphics{scheme-tmp.ps}
\end{scheme}

\renewcommand*{\schemerefformat}{\tiny\textsf}
\begin{scheme}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Second example}
  \schemeref[TMP1]{cmpd1}
  \schemeref[TMP2]{cmpd2}
  \includegraphics{scheme-tmp.ps}
\end{scheme}

\renewcommand*{\schemerefformat}{\footnotesize\itshape\sffamily}
\begin{scheme}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Third example}
  \schemeref[TMP1]{cmpd1}
  \schemeref[TMP2]{cmpd2}
  \includegraphics{scheme-tmp.ps}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm. Any chance to change the font of the labels to Helvetica? (Sorry, supervisor demands...)

Comment: Only the label font or *all* sans serif text?

Comment: Only the label font. I'd like to keep the rest of the text in regular Computer Modern.

Comment: Of course, but there might be other places where you have sans serif, e.g., headings...

Comment: No, all the rest of the document, text, headings, footnotes etc are in CM.

Comment: Then `\usepackage{helvet}` should suffice